Custom Django admin login with django allauth package
I want a functionalities where when user login to admin page, either using username and password, or using google sso (using allauth package). they still need to go for a certain check.
Now I have this views where i state my checks:
views.py
def custom_login(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            # Check if the user belongs to a specific group
            print(user)
            check_in_wd = check_user_in_wd(user)

            if (user.groups.exists() or user.is_staff) and check_in_wd:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/admin/')  # Redirect to admin dashboard after successful login
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'You are not authorized to access the admin page.')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    return render(request, 'admin/login.html', {'form': form})

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  # grappelli URLS
    path('admin/login/', custom_login, name='custom_login'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

]

login.html - just for extra refs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
{% extends "admin/login.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="content-main">
        <form id="login-form" method="post" action="{% url 'admin:login' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="id_username">{{ _('Username') }}:</label>
        {{ form.username }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="id_password">{{ _('Password') }}:</label>
        {{ form.password }}
    </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <a href="/accounts/google/login/?process=login" class="socialaccount_login provider_google">
                    <img src="https://developers.google.com/static/identity/images/branding_guideline_sample_nt_sq_lg.svg" alt="{% trans 'Sign in with Google' %}">
                </a>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>

unfortunately the custom_login only works if the user is logging in using username and password, but wont work for google sso logins, how do I fix this?
ive tried using decorators on 'admin/' but still wont work, because 'admin.site.urls' returns tuple.

urlpatterns = [
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  # grappelli URLS
    path('admin/', custom_login(admin.site.urls)),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

]

def custom_login(view_func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):


        ...same codes...


        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

this wont work. I have some idea using middleware but then it will check for every requests, which is not something i want (i only want for logins)
